# For $z=x\sin (y/x)$ with $x=r+s$ and $y=r-3s$ find $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r \partial s}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

For $z=x\sin (y/x)$ with $x=r+s$ and $y=r-3s$ find $$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r \partial s}$$

---

My try:

$$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r \partial s}=\frac{\partial }{\partial r }\frac{\partial z}{\partial s }$$
$$=\frac{\partial }{\partial r }(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x }\frac{\partial x}{\partial s }+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y }\frac{\partial y}{\partial s })$$
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial r }(\sin(y/x)+(-y/x-3)\cos(y/x))$$

$$=\color{red}{\frac{\partial }{\partial r }\sin(y/x)}+\color{blue}{\cos(y/x)\frac{\partial }{\partial r }(-y/x-3)}+\color{green}{(-y/x-3)\frac{\partial }{\partial r }\cos(y/x)}$$

$$=\color{red}{-y/x^2\cos(y/x)+1/x\cos(y/x)}$$$$+\color{blue}{(y/x^2-1/x)\cos(y/x)}$$$$+\color{green}{(y/x^2\sin(y/x)-1/x\sin(y/x))(-y/x-3)}$$

Comment: Look better at $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$, it needs a product rule and more. $\frac{\partial z }{\partial y}$ just equals $\cos(\frac{y}{x})$, while $\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}=-3$

Comment: In the future, to make sure you have all your terms, it's best to keep things abstract before plugging them in. This makes for easier bookkeeping. What you should have (in subscript notation) is $$z_{xx}x_rx_s + z_{xy}(y_rx_s+x_ry_s) + z_{yy}y_ry_s + z_xx_{rs} + z_y y_{rs}$$ It's more easily verifiable this way that our chain rule is not missing any terms now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possibility since the $(x,y)\to(r,s)$ map is quite simple (and easily invertible)

is to express $z=(r+s)\sin(\frac{r-3s}{r+s})$ and calculate directly in $r,s$.

It is a bit messy because there are a lot of terms, but the chain rule goes more smoothly, anyway you get a lot of simplifications in the end, I arrived to:

$$\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\partial r\partial s}=16\,rs\,\dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{r-3s}{r+s}\right)}{(r+s)^3}=\dfrac{(3x+y)(x-y)}{x^3}\sin\left(\frac yx\right)$$